# How do I use the 'map' method in an ActiveRecord class method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, collections, dictionary

Not sure on my Ruby syntax here.

I want to define a method that I can call like this: `client.invoices.average_turnaround`. So my `average_turnaround` method needs to work with a collection of ActiveRecord objects.

Here's my code thus far:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.average_turnaround
    return self.map(&:turnaround).inject(:+) / self.count
  end
end
```

So I'm trying to find the sum of the turnaround times for each invoice, then divide it by the total number of invoices.

Ruby is complaining that there is no `map` method defined for `Class`. I was expecting `self` to be an `Array`.

How do I write a method that works on a collection of `Invoices` and uses the `map` function? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: self wont be an Array inside the class Invoice. It will be the class itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined a class method, which is called on the class itself. What you need is an [association extension](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html). The method should be defined on your client model like this:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices do
    def average_turnaround
      return map(&:turnaround).inject(:+) / count
    end    
  end
```

Comment: Fantastic - another useful piece in the the Rails puzzle :)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use map within the class method as opposed to through an association extension. For example if it would be useful to call `Invoice.average_turnaround` directly or `Invoice.where(x: y).average_turnaround`. Place `all.` in front of `map`.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.average_turnaround
    all.map(&:turnaround).inject(:+) / all.count
  end
end
```

Use `average_turnaround` using any collection.